# asus rog strix g17 2023 BIOS failed to update / stuck on Asus EZ Flash

Tags: bios, asus

I have an ASUS ROG Strix G17 2023 mainboard that had BIOS version 324. I downloaded the version 327 BIOS update from the official website, wrote it to a USB stick and ran the Asus EZ Flasher to update the system BIOS.

The update process reached about 25% when the laptop restarted itself and booted the EZ Flasher again, offering 2 options: YES or NO. I chose YES and the same thing happened. The next time I chose NO, and it rebooted itself but booted again EZ Flasher. I cannot exit Asus EZ Flasher, the BIOS is not completing and continues to restart itself around 25%, and I cannot boot back into Windows.

I have even tried removing the USB stick but this made no difference.

How do I complete the BIOS update or, alternatively, exit it so that I can boot into Windows?

After another try: Now screen is completely black.

Comment: There's a chance that the USB drive is not good, or the copy failed. On another machine, try putting the file on another USB stick, formatted correctly (likely FAT32... *not* exFAT, ext4 or NTFS), and try installing again. See also https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/lqrnr8/rog_g15_g512lwes76_failed_bios_update_looking_for/

Comment: tried 3 different USB sticks, including the SSD itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to contact ASUS tech support in this scenario.

Otherwise, make sure to run the BIOS renamer tool after unpacking the BIOS zip file.  It's a self-contained utility that runs in DOS.  If you can run the BIOS update again using that from the SSD is better.  I've had a motherboard where I had to run the BIOS update again with the same BIOS to fix a boot loop.

I don't trust USB sticks to do BIOS updates unless it's brand new or I've tested the health of it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently BIOS version: 323

I have the same issue described by @CappY. I have a temporary solution for how to boot again on Windows if you have this loop problem. First, you press NO or just exit at the bottom of EZ Flash tool and will restart your Laptop, when your machine is restarting you press F12 to enter the Windows trouble-shooting menu. You press Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings > Restart. This will restart your machine again but this time will enter the bios menu config, there you must just press esc and enter to quit the bios menu.This is a temporary way that you can boot back to Windows OS, but if you restart or shut down the machine the EZ Flash Utility tool will show up again.

I have tried to update on all versions 323, 324 and 327, none of them worked for me, it stops on almost 15-20 % and repeats the loop described above. Any update or feedback will be useful.

Comment: I sent the laptop for repair through warranty and they fixed it somehow. 
I won't update BIOS on this ASUS ever gain.